# How do I add a read button for a product description?

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Just create a new function to process the value of get_the_content() to get only a max number of words and add a "Read more" link at the end:

```
function custom_single_product_summary(){
  $maxWords = 50; // Change this to your preferences
  $description = strip_tags(get_the_content()); // Remove HTML to get the plain text
  $words = explode(' ', $description);
  $trimmedWords = array_slice($words, 0, $maxWords);
  $trimmedText = join(' ', $trimmedWords);

  if(strlen($trimmedText) < strlen($description)){
    $trimmedText .= ' &mdash; <a href="' . get_permalink() . '">Read More</a>';
  }

  echo $trimmedText;
}
```

**It does not seem to work**
Someone can help me thanks

Comment: What does it display then?

Comment: @funkysoul It does not work

Answer (score 0):

Please check this,

```
<?php the_content( $more_link_text , $strip_teaser ); ?>
```

I found this from here [Customizing the Read More](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More)

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to apply to the product page